# Continuous User Input In Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program that takes user input, computes a result and prints it, and then waits for the next input, until the user enters a specific value to terminate the process.

What I wrote is this:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;
while (true) {
  s = sc.nextLine();
  switch (s) {
    // cases to work with the input here
    default:
      sc.close();
      return;
  }
}
```

However, this only works once, and then throws an exception. How do I get the scanner to wait for the next input each time?

Comment: it's due to the `return` statement. Why is it inside the loop?

Comment: Why are you closing the `Scanner` too as the default case?  You shouldn't close a `Scanner` opened on `System.in` at all

Comment: do you understand how a `switch` statement works?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    System.out.println("Choose an input: \n 1)A \n 2)B \n 3)C \n 4)E \n 5) q to exit\n");
    while (!(s = sc.nextLine()).toLowerCase().equals("q")) {
      switch (s) {
          case "a": System.out.println("branch A\n"); break;
          case "b": System.out.println("branch B\n"); break;
          case "c": System.out.println("branch C\n"); break;
          case "e": System.out.println("branch D\n"); break;
          default:
              System.out.println("Choose an input: \n 1)A 2)B 3)C 4)E 5) q to exit");
      }
    }
}
```

The output would be like this:

```
Choose an input: 
 1)A 
 2)B 
 3)C 
 4)E 
 5) q to exit

a
branch A

b
branch B

q
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try handling exiting `while` loop by using `if` **outside** `switch` statement:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;
        while (true) {
            s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            switch(s) {
                //cases
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (s.equals("exit")){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```